# CIVICRM menu not showing any output on frontend Joomla

Tags: joomla

Recently i updated site to Joomla 4 and also updated CIVI CRM to latest version
All works fine with upates steps.
Issue is on frontend no CIVI crm menu item working on Joomla 4
It just show on content output from the menu.
if turned off system URL [image]

With SEF OFF or if copy the menu system URL its works fine  /index.php?option=com_civicrm&view=Dashboard&task=civicrm/user&reset=1&itemid=294

Any clue where its get broken in CIVI. The routing seems not working

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same issue. Probably you use URL rewriting to get rid of /index.php/. But in the case of CiviCRM pages the page doesn't work without /index.php/. With 1000s of articles in the site and 100s of pages I can't go back to switching off rewriting. Anyone who knows how to work around this issue?

Comment: Okay, easier than I thought. Was working with the rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] after removing the '?' in that rule the CiviCRM pages appeared as they should.

Comment: I did tried that already and rewrite is off still it does not show anything.

Comment: thats not issue as routing not work in Joomla by civi core for now.

Answer (score 0):

fixed as menu link will be change when its active via a Joomla menu module and show a different url.
CIVI menu url are not sef.